# Sqlite Room Database Separate Tables Same Entities

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-design, android-room

I've different tables for per books on sql lite db, the books has 5k rows and I want to use Room database isntead of classic ways. Is it a good idea for tables has 1m+ rows creating a table for each books in a book library or are there any partition key of books table by book name? (no say create new column :) And how to create entity class of these tables has same entity?